# NGINX change phpmyadmin url

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

I recently changed the url of my site from www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com (no subdomain) running off NGINX on Ubuntu. I had phpmyadmin working at www.mydomain.com/phpmyadmin (using this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-a-lemp-server/), but after changing the url I get a white page after signing in. Is there some phpmyadmin configuration file I need to change to reflect this url change?

Comment: What's the phpmyadmin config on nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at `/etc/nginx/site-available/default` where you will need to add location /phpmyadmin

Comment: Thanks. It is strange because I can get to the logon screen just fine, but after logging in I get the white screen of death. I am going to try a complete uninstall/reinstall of phpmyadmin.

Comment: Try clearing your cache and cookies. Sometimes the easiest solutions like this helps.

Comment: A reinstall temporarily fixed it, however I have determined that it's when I try adding ssl that it breaks. I was using a self-signed ssl cert in conjunction with the "full ssl" feature on CloudFlare. Using only CloudFlare's ssl on "flexible" seems to work, so I may go with just that for now, even though I know that isn't the most secure.

Answer (score 3):

this will change your /phpmyadmin to /otherfilename and work for LEMP Server (nginx)

1. sudo apt update
2. sudo apt install phpmyadmin
3. sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
4. check your url https://server_domain_or_IP/phpmyadmin
5. update your vhost with

   ```
   location /phpmyadmin {
       root /usr/share/;
       index index.php;

       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(doc|sql|setup)/ {
           deny all;
       }

       location ~ /phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
           fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           include fastcgi_params;
           include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       }
   }
   ```
6. sudo service nginx restart
7. check again your url to access to phpmyadmin
8. cd /var/www/html/
9. ls -l
10. check phpmyadmin file
11. create a symbolic file with

    ```
    sudo mv phpmyadmin otherfilename
    ```
12. ls -l
13. check your new symbolic file and change your virtual host in 5 point to

    ```
    location /otherfilename{
        root /var/www/html/;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        location ~ ^/otherfilename/(doc|sql|setup)/ {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ /otherfilename/(.+\.php)$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        }
    }
    ```
14. sudo service nginx restart
15. check your new url https://server_domain_or_IP/otherfilename

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do it, with alias directive instead of root.

```
location /ddh73d1re1tp01hpn8sbceryzzzcp1 {
            alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;

            location ~ ^/ddh73d1re1tp01hpn8sbceryzzzcp1/(.+\.php)$ {
                     try_files $uri =404;
                     fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
                     fastcgi_index index.php;
                     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                     include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```